# Is there any tool around which generates library code automatically for Android starting from the Discovery document in the AppEngine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I Need to develop an Android application which connects to the Google App Engine.

I am able to generate the the client library code as explained by all the guides I found around, but I am concerned about the fact that the discovery document should be enough to generate the Client Library code while it is always required (at least in the docs I found) that a script is run on the code at "Server" side to generate the library (this can be done in Eclipse or with external scripts).

I found [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients) that the discovery document is used to generate Apple IOS code. I am not actually sure that there isn't any way to operate in the same way for an Android device.

What happens is (as far as I know):

```
"Backend->generation of discovery doc->client on IOS->automatic class generation->app"
"Backend->generation of discovery doc->python client->automatic class generation->app"
"Backend->generation of discovery doc->....."
"Backend->generation of Android Library->Android Java client->app"
```

so the Android client is an exception which needs a specific an additional output from the Backend developer. This extra output needs to be generated every time the backend service is modified.

Can someone help me on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Those docs describe how to generate the client library - either using a library generator for iOS, or a Python script for Android. Either way, you have to run a script, it's just two different approaches. What is the problem?

Comment: It is that I would like to use always the same source so that the person developing the server side publishes the discovery document. Client side developers create classes automatically starting from this one (if possible).

Comment: But surely that's what happens already? You don't write a discovery doc, you expose the endpoints and the doc is generated automatically. So is the Android interface.

Comment: It is slightly different, I mean there is no difference if you do both sides, but if you are supposed to develop only the Backend side you need to generate two interfaces everytime. I am going to modify the post to make it easier to be understood.

Comment: I think Jekyll is saying that the scripts to create the client code for Android takes the **server source code** as input, in stead of the using the API discovery document (as is the case when generating iOS client code). The problem is that you might not have access to the server-side source code for every API you might want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [go-endpoints documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/crhym3/go-endpoints/endpoints)

```
$ URL='https://my-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/greeting/v1/rest'
$ curl -s $URL > greetings.rest.discovery

# Optionally check the discovery doc
$ less greetings.rest.discovery

$ GO_SDK/endpointscfg.py gen_client_lib java greetings.rest.discovery
```

The go appengine SDK is available here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads